# Is getting interception request of HTTPS in clear text is a bug

Tags: request, fiddler, intercept, penetration-testing

I am intercepting HTTPS requests of android apps in my phone through Fiddler for pentesting purpose. I have installed fiddler certificate in my android phone, so that I can intercept HTTPS request.

My question is that, I can see the HTTPS requests from and to my phone in clear text in Fiddler. So, is it a bug of an android app or is it normal to see HTTPS request in clear text ?

please help I am new in pentesting world :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like anything is wrong.

HTTPS is HTTP wrapped in an encrypted tunnel created using the Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol (which in many contexts is synonymous with SSL). It sounds like you're installing the Fiddler **Certificate Authority** certificate on the phone. By doing this, you're telling the phone: "Fiddler is allowed to generate new TLS certificates for any host". The phone should then be perfectly happy to accept a TLS certificate generated by Fiddler rather than the actual app's TLS cert, Fiddler can therefore intercept the HTTPS traffic, intercept it and pass it upstream. In the real world it would be infeasibly difficult for the attacker to install a CA certificate on a target's phone, thus the attacker would be prevented from intercepting and reading the HTTPS traffic.

It is possible to force an application or user agent to only accept a given certificate (this is called certificate pinning). It's also possible to force an application to only use HTTPS (HTTP Strict-Transport-Security). There are other relevant controls but these are probably worth looking into.

In the mean time, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority.